# Backfilling new column using value from Go code

Tags: postgresql, go, architecture, flyway

What is the best way to go about backfilling a new column with values that are from Go application code? Ideally I would go through each row, call the Go code, and use the return value as the column value. The Go code is stateful. That is, it acts on data structure that is updated on every new row and from this information computes a value.

What I'm thinking about doing is having a migration that would add the new column as nullable, and then after the migration, run a Go program that would backfill the rows. However, it'd be better if all of this can be done in one migration, especially since this column should be NOT NULL from the start.

We use Flyway for migrations. Our database is Postgres 11.5.

Comment: If it is stateful, does that mean the output depends on its preceding input, i.e. the order of its input?

Comment: Yes. It acts on both the current row and what it has processed previously, which is stored in a data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to populate a new column in this way with a migration -- i.e. in a single step, inside a transaction. Instead, you want something like the following approach:

1. Update the application to gracefully handle rows with a sentinel value in the new column before timestamp 123.
2. Add the new column in a migration with a non-null constraint and the default sentinel value.
3. Run the go program to update the sentinel value to a good value for rows before timestamp 123.

This approach requires a change to the application, but doesn't require a maintenance window. It also ensures that the migration cannot fail because constraints are not met at migration time.

Comment: Ok. Where's the best place to put this program in the directory structure?

Comment: I've worked with many repos that have something like a `/devops/scripts/one-time` dir.